# Twitter-Bootstrap & IE grid system issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a new bootstrap markup for a website and it looks completely as wanted in the Google Chrome - but when I switch to IE11 it looks like the grid system is screwed.

I've specified viewport, IE=edge etc. and tried to include respond.js as various google searches suggested. The website looks fine with xs screen size but for bigger screen sizes the container overflows the window, thus not adapting to the size of the screen.

Can you help me out? The website is available at 
[thyrace.dk/etape](http://thyrace.dk/etape/) and the markup right beneath.

Thank  you very much.

```css
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@viewport           { width: device-width; }

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: white;
}
.content {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
main, aside {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li > a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: grey;
}

aside {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
aside img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}


/* Carousel */
.carousel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.carousel .item {
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #555;
}
.carousel img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-caption h4 {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(175, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.carousel-indicators {
    top: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}
.carousel-text {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;  
}

.carousel-text h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper {
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        height: auto;
        border-top: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        max-height: none;
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block !important;
        width: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-x: visible;
    }
    .navbar {
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
        border-radius: 0px;
    } 
    .navbar-nav, .navbar-nav > li, .navbar-left, 
    .navbar-right, .navbar-header {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
    }
    .navbar-logo {
        padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    }
    .page-return {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="da" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>ThyRace.dk - Løb med naturoplevelser i Thy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/purple-color-scheme.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container wrapper">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="hidden-xs page-return">
                                <a href="http://thyrace.dk">Tilbage til hovedoversigten</a>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/logo_etape.png" class="img-responsive navbar-logo hidden-xs" alt="" />
                            <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">
                                Etapeløb Thy Trail
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="visible-xs"><a href="http://thyrace.dk">Tilbage til thyrace.dk</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.htm">Løbsinformation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="rute.htm">Rute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tilmelding</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Startliste</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <img src="img/slider/1.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="img/slider/3.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img src="img/slider/4.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                </ol>
                                <div class="carousel-text">
                                    <h2>Fredag d. 30. oktober - Søndag 1. november 2015</h2>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                            </div> <!-- End carousel -->
                        </div> <!-- End carousel row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                <main> 
                                    Bla bla bla
                                </main>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                <aside>                                
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=250*100" class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=Advertisement" class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=Advertisement" class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=Some+ad" class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=Some+ad" class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=Some+ad" class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x100/000/ffffff&text=Some+ad" class="img-responsive">
                                </aside>
                            </div> <!-- End aside wrapper -->
                        </div> <!-- End main + aside row -->
                    </div> <!-- End navbar --> 
                </div> <!-- End content col -->
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "but when I switch to IE..." Don't most questions everywhere start like this?

Comment: @Rob: You're right ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DOM` is not as per `bootstrap` you've to use something like that

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
```

And You've used  `display:table` for your `wrapper` viz causing the layout issue for `IE` as well as in `FF`
Also for better results stop using your custom `class` along with `bootstrap` `class` otherwise it will misbehave at some points.

For e.g:

Instead of using:

```
<div class="col-md-6 yourClass">
```

you should use:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="yourClass">
```